# Preciso de uma API de filme que retorna Json

Tags: c#, api, xamarin-forms

Senhores tudo bom?

Alguém tem uma API de filmes que retorna json se possível com a foto do filme?

Estou fazendo alguns exemplos de app com xamarin porém a api que ele usa no exemplo n funciona mais..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Existe o [**The Open Movie Database**](http://www.omdbapi.com), é um serviço RESTful que retorna dados de filmes de diferentes fontes, para faze uma consulta de dados pode usar assim:

- `http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=The+Prestige&apikey=<sua chave de acesso>`

Que irá retornar algo como:

```
{
    "Title": "The Prestige",
    "Year": "2006",
    "Rated": "PG-13",
    "Released": "20 Oct 2006",
    "Runtime": "130 min",
    "Genre": "Drama, Mystery, Sci-Fi",
    "Director": "Christopher Nolan",
    "Writer": "Jonathan Nolan (screenplay), Christopher Nolan (screenplay), Christopher Priest (novel)",
    "Actors": "Hugh Jackman, Christian Bale, Michael Caine, Piper Perabo",
    "Plot": "After a tragic accident two stage magicians engage in a battle to create the ultimate illusion whilst sacrificing everything they have to outwit the other.",
    "Language": "English",
    "Country": "USA, UK",
    "Awards": "Nominated for 2 Oscars. Another 5 wins & 36 nominations.",
    "Poster": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMjA4NDI0MTIxNF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTYwNTM0MzY2._V1_SX300.jpg",
    "Ratings": [
        {
            "Source": "Internet Movie Database",
            "Value": "8.5/10"
        },
        {
            "Source": "Rotten Tomatoes",
            "Value": "75%"
        },
        {
            "Source": "Metacritic",
            "Value": "66/100"
        }
    ],
    "Metascore": "66",
    "imdbRating": "8.5",
    "imdbVotes": "951,885",
    "imdbID": "tt0482571",
    "Type": "movie",
    "DVD": "20 Feb 2007",
    "BoxOffice": "$53,100,000",
    "Production": "Buena Vista Pictures",
    "Website": "http://touchstone.movies.go.com/index.html?dlink=prestige",
    "Response": "True"
}
```

Então pode pegar a chave `Poster` que no exemplo acima irá retornar algo como `https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMjA4NDI0MTIxNF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTYwNTM0MzY2._V1_SX300.jpg`

No entanto é possível pegar diretamente pela URL assim:

- `http://img.omdbapi.com/?apikey=<sua chave de acesso>&...parametros_adicionais`